# can laravel & wordpress play together?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, laravel

this is my problem with laravel & WordPress:

```
    i need to put a blog inside laravel installation. 
    i want to use WordPress but i can't figure it out.
    i put the WP files inside public/blog/ but i can't install it.
    the redirect is the error part.
    i need to say that to Apache:
```

```
  if( $url = public/blog/* ){
     ignore normal laravel routing system & redirect to WordPress inside (public/blog/*)
  }
```

Comment: right way is to handle this with nginx/apache.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317031/install-wordpress-with-laravel-in-same-domain-in-folder-blog

Answer (score 1):

To keep your laravel .htaccess clean, just copy the .htaccess from any active wordpress project using clean urls (or look in wordpress doc) and copy it to your clean wordpress folder in public/bloc (it's nearly the same as for the laravel).

Without the .htaccess in your blog folder the laravel "public/.htaccess" redirect all not specific and existing files url to "public/index.php"

Answer (score 0):

to solve this I just put the laravel folder next to the wpBlog folder. 
& used namespaces to redirect the user to each based on the used url. 
SO:-

```
blog.website.com : will redirect to the wp blog
site.website.com : will redirect to the laravel website
```