# wordpress inside the laravel root as subdirectory not working

Tags: wordpress, laravel

I have a laravel5.2 project on doamin like example.com and i make a sub directory wp like example.com/wp and install the wordpres. its is working fine if i used the wordpress permalink if i used the permalink and example.com/wp/page-title its give error like route not found
Please help me i check the following post but its not working 
[Install Wordpress with Laravel in same domain in folder blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27317031/install-wordpress-with-laravel-in-same-domain-in-folder-blog)
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/install-wordpress-with-laravel-in-same-domain-in-folder-blog?page=1

Comment: You need to show us the nginx/apache (or any other web server) configuration you did for this site, including whatever you did to remove the `public` directory from Laravel, and we need to see your WP and Laravel .htaccess too. There is yet not enough information to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put wp directory inside public directory of laravel, it should work fine then:

```
example.com/wp
```

Comment: i have no public direcory. the wp is inside the www folder. where all other coce like app,vendor, resource folder is there

Comment: @NavjotSingh public directory is inside your laravel main directory where app, resources, etc are.

Comment: Yes but i remove that directory and i place all file in root direcroty

Comment: Oh, then, that is why, you modified and customized Laravel so that it doesn't use the normal directories, then, no blog post will work. You need to adjust the configuration so that it matches whatever you did there to remove the public directory in Laravel. It seems indeed the problem is your .htaccess or your apache/nginx configuration for that site. You need to adjust it, but, unless you actually explain and show us what you did to remove public, we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Here's [working solution](http://www.cesarserna.com/htaccess-rewrite-rules-laravel-lumen-wordpress/).

All you need is to modify Laravel and Wordpress `.htaccess` files as described in tutorial and restart Apache.

Comment: i have a query is it posible that we can used the laravel login inside the wordpress.
like access all the controller or function of laravel inside a plugin in laravel.and make session so that if the user login from wordpress its show  login in laravel app also